# Resample Daily Data to Monthly with Pandas (date formatting)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to resample some data from daily to monthly in a Pandas DataFrame.  I am new to pandas and maybe I need to format the date and time first before I can do this, but I am not finding a good tutorial out there on the correct way to work with imported time series data.  Everything I find is automatically importing data from Yahoo or Quandl.

Here is what I have in my DataFrame:
[dataframe segment screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCXMh.png)

Here is the code I used to create my DataFrame:

```
#Import excel file into a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(open('2016_forex_daily_returns.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='Sheet 1')

#Calculate the daily returns
df['daily_ret'] = df['Equity'].pct_change()

# Assume an average annual risk-free rate over the period of 5%
df['excess_daily_ret'] = df['daily_ret'] - 0.05/252
```

Can someone help me understand what I need to do with the "Date" and "Time" columns in my DataFrame so I can resample?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For create `DataFrame` is possible use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('2016_forex_daily_returns.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet 1')
print (df)
        Date      Time  Equity
0 2016-01-03  22:16:22  300.38
1 2016-01-04  22:16:00  300.65
2 2016-01-05  14:26:02  301.65
3 2016-01-06  19:08:13  302.10
4 2016-01-07  18:39:00  302.55
5 2016-01-08  22:16:04  308.24
6 2016-01-11  02:49:39  306.69
7 2016-01-14  15:46:39  307.93
8 2016-01-19  15:56:31  308.18
```

I think you can first cast [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) column `date` and then use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggregating functions like `sum` or `mean`:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df1 = df.resample('M', on='Date').sum()
print (df1)
             Equity  excess_daily_ret
Date                                 
2016-01-31  2738.37          0.024252

df2 = df.resample('M', on='Date').mean()
print (df2)
                Equity  excess_daily_ret
Date                                    
2016-01-31  304.263333          0.003032

df3 = df.set_index('Date').resample('M').mean()
print (df3)
                Equity  excess_daily_ret
Date                                    
2016-01-31  304.263333          0.003032
```

Comment: I think he was asking about upsampling while you showed him how to downsample

Comment: To convert daily to monthly returns (**When you don't have access to daily prices**) shouldn't you be applying `cumprod()` for regular returns? Something like `df.resample("M").apply(lambda x: ((x + 1).cumprod() - 1).last("D"))`?

Comment: @Josmoor98 - It seems good, but the best test with some data (I have no your data, so cannot test)

Comment: I have an example of returns for a particular instrument for the month of May, 2019. Shall I post as an answer?

Comment: @Josmoor98 - Sure, no problem... ;)

Comment: Posted a sample of data for reference as an answer

Answer (score 3):

To resample from daily data to monthly, you can use the `resample` method. Specifically for daily returns, the example below demonstrates a possible solution.

The following data is taken from an analysis performed by [AQR](https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Datasets/Betting-Against-Beta-Equity-Factors-Daily). It represents the market daily returns for May, 2019. The following code may be used to construct the data as a `pd.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-05-01', '2019-05-02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-06',
                         '2019-05-07', '2019-05-08', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-10',
                         '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '2019-05-16',
                         '2019-05-17', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-21', '2019-05-22',
                         '2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-27', '2019-05-28',
                         '2019-05-29', '2019-05-30', '2019-05-31'],
                         dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DATE', freq=None)

daily_returns = array([-7.73787813e-03, -1.73277604e-03,  1.09124031e-02, -3.80437796e-03,
                       -1.66513456e-02, -1.67262934e-03, -2.77427734e-03,  4.01713274e-03,
                       -2.50407102e-02,  9.23270367e-03,  5.41897568e-03,  8.65419524e-03,
                       -6.83456209e-03, -6.54787106e-03,  9.04322511e-03, -4.05811322e-03,
                       -1.33152640e-02,  2.73398876e-03, -9.52000000e-05, -7.91438809e-03,
                       -7.16881982e-03,  1.19255102e-03, -1.24209547e-02])

daily_returns = pd.DataFrame(index = index, data= may.values, columns = ["returns"])
```

Assuming you don't have daily price data, you can resample from daily returns to monthly returns using the following code.

```
>>> daily_returns.resample("M").apply(lambda x: ((x + 1).cumprod() - 1).last("D"))
-0.06532
```

If you refer to their [monthly dataset](https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Datasets/Betting-Against-Beta-Equity-Factors-Monthly), this confirms that the market return for May 2019 was approximated to be `-6.52%` or `-0.06532`.

Answer (score 1):

First, concatenate the 'Date' and 'Time' columns with space in between. Then convert that into a DateTime format using pd.to_datetime().

```
df = pd.read_excel('2016_forex_daily_returns.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet 1')
print(df)
        Date      Time  Equity
0 2016-01-03  22:16:22  300.38
1 2016-01-04  22:16:00  300.65
2 2016-01-05  14:26:02  301.65
3 2016-01-06  19:08:13  302.10
4 2016-01-07  18:39:00  302.55
5 2016-01-08  22:16:04  308.24
6 2016-01-11  02:49:39  306.69
7 2016-01-14  15:46:39  307.93
8 2016-01-19  15:56:31  308.18

df = df.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis= 'columns').set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time))
df.index.name = 'Date/Time'
print(df)
                     Equity
Date/Time                  
2016-01-03 22:16:22  300.38
2016-01-04 22:16:00  300.65
2016-01-05 14:26:02  301.65
2016-01-06 19:08:13  302.10
2016-01-07 18:39:00  302.55
2016-01-08 22:16:04  308.24
2016-01-11 02:49:39  306.69
2016-01-14 15:46:39  307.93
2016-01-19 15:56:31  308.18
```

Now you can resample to any format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a random DataFrame similar to yours here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = [x for x in pd.date_range(end=pd.datetime.today(), periods=1800)]
counts = [x for x in np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=1800)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'counts': counts}).set_index('dates')
```

Here are the procedures to aggregate the sum of counts for each week as an example:

```
df['week'] = df.index.week
df['year'] = df.index.year
target_df = df.groupby(['year', 'week']).agg({'counts': np.sum})
```

Where the output of target_df is:

```
                counts
year    week    
2015    3       29877
        4       36859
        5       36872
        6       36899
        7       37769
 .      .         .
 .      .         .
 .      .         .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a dataframe of daily returns and want them resampled to a monthly frequency in a cumulative fashion, the following approach is much faster than calling `.apply()` on every column:

```
monthly_returns = (
    returns
    .add(1).cumprod()  # Convert daily returns to cumulative
    .resample('M').last()  # Resample to get the last cumulative return of each month
    .pct_change()  # Get monthly returns as change in cumulative monthly returns
)
```

For simple returns, the approach is even simpler (pun intended):

```
monthly_returns = (
    returns
    .resample('M').last() 
    .pct_change() 
)
```